# Symfony2 Error in generated entity and timezone error in console

Tags: php, symfony, console

I tried the recently released generators yesterday but I came across a problem. I was properly able to create database & entities. But as soon as I tried to create schema it started showing error like:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:create

  [Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]                                                    
  [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Table" in class Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Post was never imported.  

doctrine:schema:create [--dump-sql] [--em[="..."]]
```

I finally found the problem, it was that the generated entity had annotations like:

```
/**
* Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Post
*
* @Table()
* @Entity
*/
```

instead of:

```
/**
* Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Post
*
* @ORM\Table(name="post")
* @ORM\Entity
*/
```

I had to add the table name in the @Table annotation and ORM\ manually to all the annotations.

Now the error has changed:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:create
ATTENTION: This operation should not be executed in a production environment.

Creating database schema...

[Exception] DateTime::__construct(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Asia/Calcutta' for 'IST/5.0/no DST' instead.

doctrine:schema:create [--dump-sql] [--em[="..."]]
```

How can I fix the timezone error.

and I saw the [Symfony Interactive Generators video](http://symfony.com/blog/symfony2-getting-easier-interactive-generators), the entity is generated by default with @ORM\ . Only the table name was for manual addition. Why did my distribution generate it with incorrect annotations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a PHP issue in your config set your [timezone](http://php.net/date_default_timezone_set)

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

There is usually a separate php.ini file for the console.

Run `php -i | grep "Configuration File"` this will tell you where the ini file for the console located. Add or edit the timezone in that file: `date.timezone = my/timezone`.

Or you could add `date_default_timezone_set()` to the top of app/AppKernel.php.

Comment: yeah but where. I can't find this setting anywhere in Symfony2 and php.ini already has a value set.

Comment: @Aayush: I haven't been using Sf2 for several weeks so maybe something changed but you can put `date_default_timezone_set()` in your bootstrap file, usually `PROJECT_ROOT/bootstrap.php`.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is the first time I have seen something happen in Symfony2. This is awesome and now I'm motivated. It generated the schema and the table. Thanks a lot.

@Crozin: It worked when placed at the top of AppKernel.php. Thanks for your answer though.

I still have one question though: Why did the console generator generate entity incorrectly?

Comment: Sorry stackoverflow just completely removed all the formatting in comment above...

Comment: @Aayush: What do you mean by *console generator generate entity incorrectly*?

Comment: It's in my question above. Generated entity had @Table() & @Column() instead of @ORM\Table() & @ORM\Column.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following code to `AppKernel.php` at the top before the class of the class file.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

Answer (score 1):

incorrect entity generation is a bug, see https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/1440

Comment: I found how to fix that. I mean it has been fixed by FabPot: https://github.com/sensio/SensioGeneratorBundle/commit/26e7dbf01adc1f6fc00cf4554eee17a93c761849